# Запятые задушили. Можно всё поснимать?

Tags: пунктуация

> Ещё одна рыбацкая деревушка, но уже на юге Франции, приобрела, не без
>   его участия, мировую славу и статус дорогого курорта – Канны.

А если:

*Ещё одна рыбацкая деревушка, но уже на юге Франции, приобрела не без его участия мировую славу и статус дорогого курорта – Канны.*

Объясните, пожалуйста, запятую после "Франции"; что она закрывает?

Comment: По-моему, без контекста разбирать это предложение бессмысленно. Уж очень чуднО оно выглядит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятых много,  а главное не выделено ("не хватает" одного тире, чтобы уравновесить одним словом всю предыдущую фразу).

Как вариант: **Ещё одна рыбацкая деревушка, уже на юге Франции, приобрела не без его участия мировую славу и статус дорогого курорта,  – Канны!**

Обособлено обстоятельство места (уже на юге Франции) со значением уточнения.

Comment: Извините, не понял ход Вашей мысли. Как Вы объясняете запятую перед тире?

Comment: Мысль простая: я же не могу поставить два тире, поэтому пришлось обойтись запятой и тире.  А если серьезно, то  согласитесь, что  "маленькие"  Канны в конце такой длинной фразы совершенно не смотрятся и не читаются. Поэтому я их выделила как могла, это авторский знак. Еще и восклицательный знак пришлось поставить с той же целью. Но при этом общее количество запятых уменьшилось, обособленное обстоятельство стало более компактным. Ну разве плохо?

Comment: Как читатель скажу, что текст стал более "читабельным". Но это на уровне чувства языка и интуиции. А формально — не знаю, как это доказать.

Comment: @Jasmin **Ну разве плохо?** Плохо. **... "маленькие" Канны... не смотрятся и не читаются...**  Дорогой курорт Канны смотрится, читается и воспринимается — вполне и везде — **без** дополнительной запятой и восклицательного знака. Это моё мнение, извините.

Comment: Разрешите также с вами не согласиться и извините за мое мнение. Грамматика  - наука формальная, а русская пунктуация основана на грамматике. А форма - это всего лишь форма, ей без разницы, о дорогом курорте или о бедной деревне идет речь. Маленькие Канны  (всего-то 5 букв) должны уравновесить 20 предыдущих слов, а это очень трудно сделать. Но есть выход, он всегда есть. Пусть автор напишет в конце: ВСЕМ ИЗВЕСТНЫЕ, НИ С ЧЕМ НЕ СРАВНИМЫЕ. ВЕЛИКОЛЕПНЫЕ КАННЫ,  и тогда одного тире будет достаточно

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что выражение "не без его участия" не нуждается в обособлении, т.к. по смыслу практически равно "с его участием" (выступает в роли наречия).
[Приобрела (как? каким образом?) не без его участия.]

*Ходят слухи, что **не без его участия** так своевременно захлебнулся в сладком вине Джордж Кларенс, как только стало известно, что ...*
С. Вилар. Тяжесть венца

*Он налил себе полный стакан вина и выпил его, радуясь от всего сердца при мысли о том, что грехопадение его преосвященства епископа совершается **не без его участия**.*
А. Дюма. Виконт де Бражелон, или Десять лет спустя

Сравните (смысл почти тот же):
Ещё одна рыбацкая деревушка, но уже на юге Франции, приобрела с его участием мировую славу и статус дорогого курорта – Канны.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение "не без его участия" обособляется в зависимости от контекста. Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса, в которых это выражение обособлено, так как играет роль уточнения.

Организация работы, не без участия КГБ, была самая высокая, правда, изматывала людей. [Анатолий Докучаев. Охота за «призраком» // «Воздушно-космическая оборона», 2002-2003]

Между ними и местными, не без участия Бекова, произошла стычка. [Убойная совесть (2003) // «Сельская новь», 2003.11.11]

В Вашем вопросе контекст отсутствует, но вероятнее всего, речь идет об одном из ряда событий, произошедших "не без его участия". Если это так, то обособление **неуместно** (это не уточнение).

Согласен с Jasmin: "уже на юге Франции" обособляется как уточнение.

Comment: Здесь дело не только в смысле,  но и в структуре предложения.  Оборот (достаточно объёмный) может вписываться или не вписываться в предложение. Если автор захочет его выделить, то найдет такое место, что не обособить его будет невозможно. В нашем примере обособление совсем не помешало бы, но нельзя ставить такое количество запятых и обособлять обе конструкции (пришлось выбрать уточнение обстоятельства).  Поэтому оборот (хотя и с некоторым трудом) вписался в основное предложение.